# wordpress wp all import issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I'm using WP all import to import many products with 3 languages(separately exported by category using WP all export).
I exported CSV file products to edit and make changes prices and meta tags of images.
I changed what I wanted and tried to import by export template.. but unfortunately, missed images, prices without changes and attributes disappeared on product card.

I tried by option update existing products and with all options of the plugin 5-6 times..
importing without error but there is no changes..
no images
no updated price value
disappeared attributes

if anyone know any solutions or recommendations how to fix this problem.. please share. thank you for all

url website: https://m-lux.lv/en/metala-durvis-dzivokliem/

https://prnt.sc/10c81z1
https://prnt.sc/10c82jd

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers of the WP All Import plugin yet? If not, it might be a good idea to do so: [WP All Import Support Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-all-import/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import products in multiple languages, you need to use a special "unique identifier" field to link the translations. It cannot be the same as any other field, like SKU.

From doc:

> When you import the files later, WP All Import will need a way to
> match the default language posts to their corresponding translations
> in the other files.
>
> To do this, you need to specify a unique identifier for each post.
> Assign an ID number to one of your posts in your default language.
> Then, use that same ID number for the same post in your secondary
> language files. By looking at this ID, you can tell which post is the
> translation of another by finding the same ID number in your files.

https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/wpml-all-import-plugin-website-import-with-wpml/

I also recommend to make 2 separate imports: one for simple products only, the other - for variable products.

Test each import on just 1 product first to see if it's working (it's quicker).

Comment: I just want update products value(price, image seo tags).. I exported by category.. or did I export incorrectly? thank you

Comment: Possibly. As I mentioned: export 1 simple product, try to import it, same with variable product. Make sure you’re using unique identifier on import.